# Multiple Stackoverflow Profiles

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

I just saw this, I have two Stackoverflow profiles, one tied to Facebook & one tied to Gmail. Is there a way to merge?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801